# How to decorate static html pages in IIS with .NET technologies

Tags: .net, iis, decorator

We have a website project. Its content will be coded in static html (files with html extension) and developed by different vendors. This website will run on IIS.

I hope to be able to decorate these pages in the sense of using the Decorate pattern. By decorating, I mean when a static page is requested, the system retrieves the page, add additional banner (for example: logo and menu), footer, and some hidden stuff (such as google web stats tracking code). Then the system sends final content (the static page, plus banner, footer, etc.) to the requesting browser.

I came from the Java world, and there is a few tools that I allow me to do so without modifying the static html files (such as inserting a few lines of code in order to use "layout"). This decorator approach can obviously benefit us,  the content vendors, and the website in many ways.

Is there anything similar I can use in the .Net and IIS world?

Thanks for any input and ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet in this case might be to developer a custom IIS Handler. You can do that in .NET and configure which specific paths the handler should pay attention to. This can be a wildcard entry, so that you can (for instance) have it handle *.html files and let IIS handle *.gif files. Your handler code would open the relevant file, perform your additions, and then send the content to the browser.

This article gives good information on how to write this: http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/runtime-extensibility/developing-iis-modules-and-handlers-with-the-net-framework

Note that you'll want to think carefully about performance implications, since IIS serves up static pages very fast.

Comment: John, I am interested in the handler approach. Just to be curious. .Net/IIS has been around for so long. There should be needs like mine so that somebody might have already coded a generic hanlder that takes a config  file (for specific path and for the layout to use). Is my need unique?

Comment: I'm not sure I know of any; on the other hand, it wouldn't surprise me if you could find an open source handler that does what you're looking for. I haven't really run into this need much in the past.